# Lwc Wired method result is not in proper format

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have below script in .js file.

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
wiredSandAnalysis({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.yValues = [];
        data.fields.forEach(field => { // here I am getting the error.
            this.yValues.push(field.value);
        });
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
```

I can see in debug logs that records are successfully returned by Apex method. But I am getting below error.

```
aura_prod.map.js:42142 TypeError: b.fields.forEach is not a function
    at wiredAccount (chartWrapper.js:4)
    at t.dispatchEvent (aura_prod.js:13)
    at Object.next (lds.js:2)
    at fa.next (lds.js:2)
    at Ca._nextWithErrorHandling (lds.js:2)
    at eval (lds.js:2)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Ca.emitValue (lds.js:2)
    at eval (lds.js:2)
    at Ta.eval [as next] (lds.js:2)
```

Upon logging the result in the console I found that the fields are placed into `originalTarget`. but it should be in `data.fields`.

[image: originalTarget]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data.fields` returns Object and not array, so `Object.keys(data.fields)` will give array of field API names. If you are trying to collect all the values of the fields, you can use below:

```
if (data) {
    this.yValues = [];
    Object.keys(data.fields).forEach((field) => {
        // here I am getting the error.
        this.yValues.push(data.fields[field].value);
    });
    console.log('Account => ', JSON.stringify(this.yValues));
} else if (error) {
    this.error = error;
}
```

For your reference, below is how you get response in `getRecord`:

**SAMPLE RESPONSE:**

```
{
  "apiName": "Account",
  "childRelationships": {

  },
  "fields": {
    "Description": {
      "displayValue": null,
      "value": "University of Boston _ from contact flow"
    },
    "Name": {
      "displayValue": null,
      "value": "University of Boston n"
    }
  },
  "id": "00128000009j45sAAA",
  "lastModifiedById": "00528000001IIBvAAO",
  "lastModifiedDate": "2019-08-25T14:37:49.000Z",
  "recordTypeInfo": null,
  "systemModstamp": "2019-08-25T14:37:49.000Z"
}
```